# How to tell the debugger to ignore breaking on thrown exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, debugging

I have a TextBox in which I validate the input with a third party library. However, this library throws custom exceptions when the syntax is incorrect. This is not a real big deal, except for when you are debugging.

When debugging, since the text in the TextBox will always be initially wrong (I am still typing it),  the debugger will stop after each letter until it is correct, which is really annoying as I validate with each letter.

**How can I tell the debugger to not break at these custom exceptions?**

*P.S. I have already tried to filter the Debug -> Exceptions (added it in `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`), but this did not work for me. The debugger still stops at the line where the library is called.*

P.P.S. Using Visual Studio 2010.

[image: For the non-believers]

**Answer:**

In the end I was very close with my PS. It was a pretty silly mistake: I had a typo in the namespace. Thanks to Pop Catalin and Madhur Ahuja for pointing it out!

Comment: It has a try/catch.. debugger still breaks inside the try though..

Comment: it breaks inside the try? wow thats new to me

Comment: @Arcturus: And if uncheck all items in the Exceptions-Dialog?

Comment: @Bobby, don't really want that.. I still want the debugger to break on other exceptions.

Comment: You must have changed default settings because I've never seen it break in the try either. Well, not without a breaking point anyways.

Comment: Added an image for the non-believers ;)

Comment: @Arcturus, have you added the fully qualified exception name in the Visual Studio exception dialog ?

Comment: @Pop.. Thats it!! :) It had a typo in it! :) Thanks :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> There is an 'exceptions' window in
>   Visual Studio ... try Ctrl-Alt-E when
>   debugging and click on the 'Thrown'
>   checkbox for the exception you want to
>   stop on

You are looking for reverse of this:
[Visual Studio: How to break on handled exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to break when the exception occurs unexpected you really should hide the method from the debugger using the `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]` method.

Comment: There seems to be a bug with this approach in MSVS 2015 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382551

Answer (score 9):

Debug + Exceptions, click the Add Button.  Set the type to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and the Name to the full name of the custom exception, including the namespace name.  You can now untick the Thrown box for this one, expand the node first if necessary.

Comment: Spot on worked like a charm. Had an exception thrown every time I debug for 6 months.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: `[DebuggerHidden]`

Comment: Doesn't work, because it stops debugger on one level up in callstack from the method with [DebuggerHidden]. It may work for event handlers though.

Comment: @Klaus, agree, I'm not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382551

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a bug in the debugger, it was a intentional change.  While
>   the behavior is different and can be confusing, it had to be changed
>   in Visual Studio 2010 to support several other scenarios including
>   Silverlight debugging.

1. Disable "break on user unhandled exceptions" for the exception types you you are encountering here (via Debug -> Exceptions)
2. Disable "break on user unhandled exceptions" for all exceptions (via Debug -> Exceptions)

For more details please refer the link here.

[Breaking on exceptions in VS2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/25bdf149-5133-4f47-bbf2-1d4ca638fee9)

Comment: That change really sucks, because I *want* to break on *unhandled* exceptions, but these exceptions are definitely handled.