# how can I prevent swallowed exceptions in 3rd party libraries from triggering the VS debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

```
 using System;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using NUnit.Framework;

 namespace TestExperiment
 {
     [TestFixture]
     internal class TestAAA
     {
         [Test]
         public void Test_ThrowSwallowThirdParty()
         {
             ThrowSwallowThirdParty();
         }

         [Test]
         public void Test_ThrowSwallowLocal()
         {
             ThrowSwallowLocal();
         }

         [DebuggerStepThrough]
         [DebuggerNonUserCode]
         [DebuggerHidden]
         public void ThrowSwallowThirdParty()
         {
             ThirdPartyLibrary.ThrowEmbedded();
         }

         [DebuggerStepThrough]
         [DebuggerNonUserCode]
         [DebuggerHidden]
         public void ThrowSwallowLocal()
         {
             try
             {
                 throw new Exception();
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
             }
         }
     }

     // imagine this is a 3rd party library provided in a dll which I am referencing
     internal static class ThirdPartyLibrary
     {
         public static void ThrowEmbedded()
         {
             try
             {
                 throw new Exception();
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420390/dont-stop-debugger-at-that-exception-when-its-thrown-and-caught) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499473/how-to-tell-the-debugger-to-ignore-breaking-on-thrown-exceptions) I understand you can use the `[DebuggerHidden]` attribute to prevent the debugger from stopping at a swallowed exception even if it is told to break on all thrown exceptions. This works for `Test_ThrowSwallowLocal()`. However I would like to duplicate this when calling code in a 3rd party library which is throwing and swallowing its own exceptions - which I am trying to emulate in `Test_ThrowSwalloThirdParty()` - at the moment the debugger continues to break at the exception throw.

Is there a way to avoid this without editing the ThirdPartyLibrary code (which I cannot easily do?)

Comment: is this in visual studio in debug or when just running the application ?

Comment: It used to work just fine before VS2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the [Just My Code Option in VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/25/understanding-just-my-code.aspx)

Comment: I changed the link to a blog