# Debuggin blocked by other exceptions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm troubleshooting a solution which a very large code base using step by site debugging in Visual Studio. There are a lot of things going on in the background and a client application makes regular calls to the backend. When I'm debugging the calls create exceptions. So when I'm stepping through the code suddenly I jump to some exception handling code that among other things logs.

This makes it very hard to find the exceptions that has to do with the issue I'm troubleshooting. Is there some way to make the debug stepping ignore what is not part of the thread I am currently in?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to make the debugg steping ignore what is not part of the thread i am currently in

You can use **Exception Settings** to ignore those exceptions, Debug->Windows->Exception Settings (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

You can set whether these exceptions always break, or only break when it's an unhandled exception:

> Debug + Exceptions, click the Add Button. Set the type to "Common
>   Language Runtime Exceptions" and the Name to the full name of the
>   custom exception, including the namespace name. You can now untick the
>   Thrown box for this one, expand the node first if necessary.

Certify: [How to tell the debugger to ignore breaking on thrown exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499473/how-to-tell-the-debugger-to-ignore-breaking-on-thrown-exceptions)

Besides, you can check the blog [The New Exception Settings Window in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) for some more details.