# What option in Visual Studio let catching exception where it occurred?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

VS 2010. The same WPF project, debug mode, two computers:

- A -- when exception occurrs the caret is placed at the point of exception
- B -- when the exception occurrs, correct exception is shown but  caret is always placed at "win.ShowDialog()" in App.xaml.cs -- this is main entry for showing & running my application, in such case it is very tiresome to track down where the exception occurred

What kind of settings control such behaviour? Of course I would like to switch B, so when exception hits I would be placed at the point of exception, not at the main entry.

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you'd want to break the IDE on the line where the exception has been thrown ?

It is in the Debug menu, under exceptions.  There you can check a checkbox that 'll make sure the IDE breaks in the code and shows the line where the exception has been thrown.

Comment: Ha! Great, thank you (why I had different settings on exceptions -- God knows).

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is asking about SEH, and catching "First class exceptions", which naturally requires SEH exception handling, not sure if this is still true in C#.

Comment: I don't know what is SEH, but I wanted VS to stop at the line which caused the exception, not when exception is passed all the way up, to the main entry of application.

Comment: Found it -- Structured Exception Handling ;-)