# Visual Studio (2008) debugging stopped showing me where my exception occurred for C#

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I used to get exceptions and the application would stop and the debugger would show where the exception happened.  I've since added 'using System.Diagnostics' and a few debugging lines.  Now, I just get a message 'A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in RethinkFilesystem.dll' or something similar in the Output window and my app kinda breaks. What did I do to change the behavior? How can I go back?

Comment: Post code so we know what exactly you did.

Comment: my solution is like dozens of files; i think it's more of a setting thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on stop on thrown exception in debugger. That is in visual studio, go to Debug->Exceptions then tick the box thrown next to clr exceptions.

[Visual Studio: How to break on handled exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

There's an option under Debug > Exceptions... that allows you control the behavior of handled an unhandled exceptions. Checking 'Thrown' next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions will break the debugger when any listed .Net exception is thrown, regardless if it is handled.