# Avoid debugger halt on caught exception in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible not have the debugger stop at the throw statement, while keeping the same functionality?
I've asked around and it seems not, but I thought I'd give stackoverflow a try before I accept that's it's not possible.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new MyClass();
        var t = new Task(o.DoStuff);
        t.Start();

        try
        {
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        throw new Exception("Testing"); // debugger stops here!
    }
}
```

Comment: "while keeping the same functionality" what functionality is it that you want to keep? So far, you've described a single behaviour, and that's the one you're asking to get rid of.

Comment: What I meant by that is that I don't want to handle the exception in the thread, but keep it in main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Exceptions` windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> in Visual Studio. Click on which exception you want to unhandled.

Also check: [Visual Studio: How to break on handled exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions)

[image]

Comment: Seems interesting, I'll test it out