# Change Slider's value in XAML throw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, exception

I have a problem with WPF : I would like use a slider in my XAML with an default value but when i do it, an exception is thrown :

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`

this is my code:

```
<Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="sliderVolume" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Grid.Row="2" ValueChanged="volume_ValueChanged" Margin="598,35,12,0" Value="100"/>
```

and this is my code is .cs :

```
private void volume_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    mediaElement.Volume = sliderVolume.Value;
}
```

without the default value

`Value"100"`

It works !

Comment: Maybe you should post the `volume_ValueChanged` event code.

Comment: private void volume_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) {mediaElement.Volume = sliderVolume.Value;}

Comment: Have you tried enabling "first chance" exceptions in the debugger, to catch the precise moment when the exception occurs?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions  Try that and update the question with some additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume.aspx) . Maximum volume allowed is 1.

> The media's volume represented on a linear scale between 0 and 1. The
>   default is 0.5.

So you need to set your slider like this :

```
<Slider Value="0.5" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Name="sliderVolume" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Grid.Row="2"
ValueChanged="volume_ValueChanged" Margin="598,35,12,0" />
```

Code :

```
private void volume_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> args)
      {
         mediaElement.Volume = (double)sliderVolume.Value;
      }
```

Comment: Always the same, it works fine, nevertheless an exception is thrown without blocks try{} catch{}

Comment: ok it's works fine now.
In my xaml I declared my mediaElement after my slider, so when I ran my projet, mediaElement was NULL.
I'm sorry and Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a minimum and maximum value defined.  Your "default" value may be out of range.

Answer (score 1):

The [MediaElement volume property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume.aspx) is represented on a linear scale between 0 and 1.

Try:

```
mediaElement.Volume = sliderVolume.Value / 10;
```

Comment: It works now, but without block try{} catch{} an exception is thrown every time.

Comment: Add AbZy's slider Xaml with mediaElement.Volume = sliderVolume.Value;

Comment: Can you post the inner exception?