# Parallel.ForEach is not executing the method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, foreach, task-parallel-library

I'm attempting to Parallelize the following For Each loop which works as expected. I started with this:

```
foreach (DataRow drGroup in dsGroups.Tables["Table"].Rows)
         ProduceInvoices(drGroup);
```

and changed it to:

```
Parallel.ForEach<DataRow>((IEnumerable<DataRow>)dsGroups.Tables["Table"].Rows, ProduceInvoices)
```

however `ProduceInvoices` seem to no longer get executed, despite dsGroup containing rows.

Please can you provide me with any pointers and/or where to look?

Comment: You should have had some kind of invalid cast exception thrown, do you have a empty `catch` somewhere that was swallowing the error? Also turning on [breaking on handled exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions) can also be helpful in tracking this kind of stuff down.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - It's a really poorly written legacy app so more than likely has the odd empty `catch`, otherwise would've spotted this.  Next time I'll try and break on handled exceptions, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Parallel.ForEach<DataRow>(dsGroups.Tables["Table"].AsEnumerable(), ProduceInvoices);
```

`Rows` property returns a `DataRowCollection` which doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you! I really should've noticed this myself instead of trusting resharper with the cast!