# LINQ query which converts XML document to object list causing exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a pretty large LINQ query which reads XML nodes into object properties, however a line in my query is causing a System.FormatException exception based on "Input string not in a correct format".

```
DeliveryFee = x.Descendants("LineItemShipping").Select(e => (double)e.Element("TotalPrice")).FirstOrDefault(),
```

> (double)e.Element("TotalPrice")  // this text in the line is highlighted by the debugger so this element must be the cause

There is 1000's of records in the XML document so I am having trouble locating the record causing the exception, is there a way I can "throw" the value causing the error to a catch() statement?  I'm not exactly sure how to debug a LINQ query to get the value at runtime and I'm sure it's just an issue where that XML node is empty for this specific record.  (or contains an illegal character)

I know it's a specific record as I can pull many rows without an issue however when I try to pull a specific subset that's when I get the exception, so I know it is localized to a months worth of data but I am unable to narrow it down more.

Comment: You could just run `DeliveryFee = x.Descendants("LineItemShipping").Where(e => (double?)e.Element("TotalPrice") == null).FirstOrDefault(),`

Comment: Provide sample XML please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find this bug, first enable [breaking when an exception is thrown in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions), via `Debug` -> `Exceptions`.  Either enable breaking on *all* exceptions, or enable breaking on `System.FormatException`.

Now Visual Studio will stop when an exception is thrown for a `LineItemShipping`node with an invalid `TotalPrice`.  Then, in the [immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx), you can use the [`AncestorsAndSelf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346865%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find the problematic node by typing:

```
e.Element("SomeStatus").AncestorsAndSelf().ToArray()
```

Visual Studio will show you the path of `XElement`'s that generate the exception.  This should allow you to find the problematic XML node.

Comment: This helped me track down the record causing the issue.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a try catch statement to the select expression, something like this:

```
    var DeliveryFee = x.Descendants("LineItemShipping").
        Select(e => {
            try
            {
                var item = (double)e.Element("TotalPrice");  
                return item;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //This is just so it will compile and have a return value                        
                return double.MinValue;
            }                  
        }).
        FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `(double)` to `(double?)` to handle empty cases and a `?? 0` to convert nulls to zero:

```
(double)(x.Descendants("LineItemShipping")
          .Select(e => (double?)e.Element("TotalPrice")).FirstOrDefault()) 
          ?? 0)
```