# Debug mode of Visual Studio 2010 is not running well

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I've problem in my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version. When I push play button on my project and the browser (IE) is appear and suddenly the play button is not gray out and in a debug mode position. It's back to normal mode as I'm not pressing the button play yet. Please help and advice the solution. Attached image for the illustration.

Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XPJM.png

Answer (score 0):

something makes your program exit.
perhaps exception.
start debugging using F11 (step into).
and and go slowly until you find the reason.

also you can use 
[Visual Studio: How to break on handled exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions)

Comment: I've reset the environment setting to C# mode. Anyway thanks Nahum for the link.