# debug and start without debug on exception handling

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, try-catch

I am looking into the exception handling on tasks with below program.
The program runs fine and exception was handled if I run with Ctrl + F5. However, it stopped at the throw exception line when I run with F5.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() => test()).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught");
        }
    }

    private static Task test()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I wonder if my test program is working(caught the exception). Could this relate to my Visual Studio setting(I am using VS2013). 
Thank you

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/116934/1997232), you want to do opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly throwing an exception and not catching it. That causes the problem when you build the solution. 
Catch the Exception which is thrown using try/catch

```
 private static Task test()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NotImplementedException");                
            }

        }
```

you can write a general exception also instead of NotImplementedException.