# NullReferenceException Not Catched

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I am using wcf Service, and When I called it like below,

```
 try
 {
      //var of1 = CrmStartUp.GetOfferDetailsById(5070, 666, 1, 2016, 18);
      LostReasonsByOffer lostReasonsByOffer145 = CrmStartUp.GetLostReasonsByOffer(5070);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

then I got

> nullreference Exception

and it is not caught by the SystemException Class.
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or How to fix this issue.

the error is shown below

[image]

Comment: Check threads when execution stops. It might happen that the uncaught exception was thrown on a different thread - just guessing, but worth checking.

Comment: Post the *full* exception, including its call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Almost certainly the error occurs somewhere else

Comment: BTW the image doesn't show that the exception isn't caught. That's the image *before* jumping to the exception handler. BTW, such handlers are a very bad idea - like sticking a circuit breaker to the up position instead of fixing a short circuit

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that it isn't being caught? It could just be showing up in the debugger due to your visual studio settings as per this answer

[Visual Studio: How to break on handled exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions#116934)

You could either try running it in a "release" configuration rather than the "debug" configuration, not running it in the debugger or changing your visual studio debug settings.

That's the only thing that springs to mind.

EDIT: As Panagiotis Kanavos notes, it's also worth highlighting that an empty catch block is most often a bad practice.

Comment: That's exactly what the image shows - the exception being *thrown*. The OP probably confused the message for an uncaught exception