# C# crashes despite try/catch block

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, visual-studio-2019

I think I had  a configuration problem of the visual studio 2019 exception setting, which I am not able to solve.

I am trying to catch a simple exception, using try/catch block.

on one pc it works as intended (shows a message box), on other pc - using visual studio 2019, the program crashes, show the exception on the code it self. only after pressing the "continue" button, a message is shown.

both pc's are windows 10, running vs19.

I assumed that it is more a configuration problem, then a code problem (running the same code on both pc's).

please see code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
   

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Capture _capture;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _capture = new Capture(2);
        }

        private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           try
           {
                var img = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
                var bmp = img.Bitmap;
                picBoxCapture.Image = bmp;
           }

           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
        }


    }}
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions)

Comment: John, unfortunally no.

Comment: Not even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681894/3181933)?

Comment: I agree with John: it really does sound like you have one Visual Studio set up to break when the exception is thrown and not the other one.

Comment: I third that - you said yourself it's a configuration problem - the configuration is the exception settings in one instance of VS19