# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException in external code? Source not available

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Scratching my head here...

I am using VS 2022 with 4.8 Framework

I am getting a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An invalid argument was supplied' error when I try to launch my app.

[image]

It doesn't show me the line it's caused by or anything. I don't use any networking in my application however I do connect to SQL and Active Directory and am thinking that could be causing it? Not really sure. I am at a total loss is there anything I can do to further identify what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: is is possible that you have "first chance exceptions" enabled or similar? normally I would expect to get this much later, back in your code, and then you can see the stack-trace

Comment: Can you tell me where that setting is? It seems that when I copied it off the network share to my local desktop and run it that the error stops and the application runs fine. I need it to run from a share however.

Comment: Presumably the opposite of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions